# Use a button inside a table to open a modal by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a problem with my code and I don't know how to solve it.
I have a list of products that I import by the command `$('#allconta').load` inside of a `<tbody id="allconta">`. I've put a button in each line to edit the product that open a modal, but I'm not succeeding.

The table rows are generated by a `while()`, that return this code:

```
echo "
<tr>
    <td>".$row['pid']."</td>
    <td>".$det['name']."</td>
    <td>".$opts_show."</td>
    <td>".date_format($hora,"H:i")."</td>
    <td>".number_format($valor, 2, ',', ' ')."</td>
    <td><a name='editaitem' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' id='".$row['id']."'>
<span class='icon-edit'></span></a></td>
</tr>";
```

I've tried to use this code, but don't works:

```
$('a[name="editaitem"]').on('click',function(){
        $('#editped').modal('show');
    });
```

Please anyone help me find the answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: this means `$('#editped').modal('show');` you are trying to open bootstrap modal and with your current approach I suggest use class `$('.openmodal').on('click',function(){` and in <a> link add `class='btn btn-primary btn-xs openmodal'`

Comment: I've tried this... but don't work :(  please, take a look: http://gabrielvargas.zz.mu/caixa.php

Comment: you haven't changed this `$('a[name="editaitem"]').on('click',function(){` in `caixa_script.js` check here http://jsfiddle.net/48qdykq0/1/

Comment: I think the problem is not with how you try to open the modal problem is when you load data via `$('#allconta').load` on page, where modal and it's call already exist but the button which opens the modal comes with `$('#allconta').load` which is dynamic so it's not binding with the jQuery to open modal

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalID"` in which the #ModalID here would be the id value of the modal you wanted to show. Hope this helps.

```
<a name='editaitem' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' id='".$row['id']."'data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalID'>
   <span class='icon-edit'></span>
</a>
```

Comment: what's wrong with OP's current approach where he want's to open the modal with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I guess you are using bootstrap modal. In order to open a modal(Bootstrap) by clicking a link you need to provide the modal id reference to the href attribute of the link and add data-toggle="modal" to the link and it will work like a breeze. Try following code:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">click</a>
```

If you want you can put the modal id in data-toggle attribute instead of href. Its completely on your choice. This has been tested on Bootstrap version 3.x.x. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzdfmckw/). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I saw Shehary's comment and he is right. As you are loading the data using `$('#allconta').load` it may an issue of binding because you are trying to trigger modal with jQuery using a link(anchor tag) that was not in the DOM initially when the page was loaded. If it is the problem of binding then you can try the following code to show modal and it will work:

```
$(document).on('click','a[name="editaitem"]', function(){
        $('#editped').modal('show');
    });
```

Hope it helps.